# how to pass dynamic url values into the context dictionary?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

blog_confirm_delete.html

```
<form method="POST" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <h2>Are you sure you would like to delete this post?</h2>
  <button type="submit" value="send" class="btn btn-danger">Yes, Delete</button>
  <button class="btn btn-info mb-8">
    <a class="text-white" href="{% url 'blog-detail' post.id %}">Cancel</a>
  </button>
</form>
```

views.py

```
class BlogDeleteView(SuccessMessageMixin,LoginRequiredMixin,TeacherOwnerPassesTestMixin,DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "postings/blog_confirm_delete.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('blog-list')
    success_message = "Your post has been deleted!"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['list_title'] = "Our Blog"
        context['list_url'] = "blog-list"
        context['detail_title'] = "Delete Post"
        context['cancel'] = ???
        return context
```

So currently I have to hard code the "Cancel" button's url for every "X_confirm_delete.html" template that I have. Now I would like to pass in a dynamic url value for each DeleteView so that I can reduce all DeleteView into using one simple template. How can I do this?

Thank you for helping me in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`'HTTP_REFERER'`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META) for returning to that view. Like this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['list_title'] = "Our Blog"
    context['list_url'] = "blog-list"
    context['detail_title'] = "Delete Post"
    context['cancel'] = self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/')
    return context
```

And add it to template:

```
<a class="text-white" href="{{cancel}}">Cancel</a>
```